# Get Google Calendar Events in an Android App

Tags: java, android, events, time, google-calendar-api

I just started using Android for app development. I wanted to pull in my calendar events from Google Calendar and then use them for running a counter with the phone's time.

As in: If an event starts at 6.00 pm and ends at 7.00 pm:

then if phone time <6.00 pm then print "Time till event" + time left till event

```
 if phone time >6.00 pm but < 7.00 pm then print "Time left" + time till 7.00
```

Can someone point me to some resource which enables me to do that? I primarily use Java for development and was hoping to utilize some available library which simplified this operation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is what you want:

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), new String[]{ "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, null, null);         
//Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, null);
String add = null;
cursor.moveToFirst();
String[] CalNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < CalNames.length; i++) {
    CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
    CalNames[i] = "Event"+cursor.getInt(0)+": \nTitle: "+ cursor.getString(1)+"\nDescription: "+cursor.getString(2)+"\nStart Date: "+new Date(cursor.getLong(3))+"\nEnd Date : "+new Date(cursor.getLong(4))+"\nLocation : "+cursor.getString(5);
    if(add == null)
        add = CalNames[i];
    else{
        add += CalNames[i];
    }           
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.calendars)).setText(add);

    cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
```

credits : @Vinay

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want only events happening between a timespan (otherwise you quickly would end up with too many events), the way to go, is to use the [Instances](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html) helper of the CalendarContract API (see my blog post about [the CalendarContract content provider](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/)).

Here's how to find out about events:

```
   long begin = // starting time in milliseconds
   long end = // ending time in milliseconds
   String[] proj = 
         new String[]{
               Instances._ID, 
               Instances.BEGIN, 
               Instances.END, 
               Instances.EVENT_ID};
   Cursor cursor = 
         Instances.query(getContentResolver(), proj, begin, end);
   if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
      // do s.th. meaningful with your result set
   }
```

The nice thing about this helper is, that it takes care of the visibility of events. For example deleted/cancelled events are visible until the next sync - otherwise Android couldn't tell the backend to delete the event there as well. You could do so yourself, but it gets complicated if you want to consider all day events, visibility and what not. Always use Instances!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(
                    Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                    new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                            "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, 
                    null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // fetching calendars name 
    String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    // fetching calendars id 
    nameOfEvent.clear();
    startDates.clear();
    endDates.clear();
    descriptions.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

        nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
        startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
        endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
        descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
        CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
        cursor.moveToNext();

    } 
    return nameOfEvent;
}
```

Comment: That's looks like a nice piece of code, but could you please add some context to it? It would be great if you could edit your post and add an explaination to the code.